# Extract values from custom post response in Angular 5 HttpClient

Tags: angular, httpclient

I have a Rest service which sends the data back in JSON format as below:

```
{result:"success",message:"token"}
```

**HttpClient Post Function used to get above response**

```
getAuthResponse(username: string, password: string): Observable<Callback> {
    return this.http.post<Callback>('https://rest-service-url/Prod/authenticate', {
      'operation': 'AuthUser',
      'data': {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
      }
    });
  }
```

**Callback Class**

```
export class Callback {
  constructor(
    public result: string,
    public message: string
  ) {}
}
```

My getAuthResponse is returning an Observable of custom type callback.

Now I am trying to extract the message in one of my other service like below.

```
this.dataservice.getAuthResponse(username, password).subscribe(
      res => {
        const callback = <Callback>res;
        console.log(callback.message);
      }
    );
```

I can print res and I see the response in JSON format like below

```
{result:"success",message:"some message"}
```

But I get undefined when I try to print callback.message.

I read that in new HttpClient module, http.post will automatically map the response into the type specified. Is that true or do we need to map it to callback class (in mycase) explicitly?

Can you please help me in extracting the message value from my Post response?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix. The issue was with the custom response posted by my rest service. I formatted the response data into json in my rest service and I am able to extract the values without any issue.

**EDIT**
Initially the call back code in my Node.js Rest Service was

```
callback('{"result":"success","message": "' + jwtToken + '"}');
```

I changed it as below

```
var callbackMsg = {
                        'result': 'success',
                        'message': jwtToken
                    };
                    callback(callbackMsg);
```

Comment: Where did you change? Paste the code here to help other users.